Angular Standalone - How to Inject Service into Service
I'm a longtime Angular dev now trying to learn the standalone version. How do I inject a service into another service without a providers array in the NgModule. Is my only choice using providedIn in the Injectable declaration?

Check this link:
https://angular.dev/guide/di/creating-injectable-service#injecting-services-in-other-services
If you would like to use injection context, read this:
https://angular.dev/guide/di/dependency-injection-context#run-within-an-injection-context

I've found this guide useful about standalone in general: https://v17.angular.io/guide/standalone-components#providing-services-to-a-subset-of-routes You can inject your service if not providedIn: 'root' in: component's providers array, a route providers array or the main bootstrapApplication providers array AFAIK

Thanks @GiancarloSotelo I will review these links.

And @davidlj95 too!

If your service is not providedIn: root, then you must be adding the service to the providers array of some standalone component (in-order to use it). You need to add the second service to the same array, so that the service has its own instance of the second service.
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FirstService } from './app/first.service';
import { SecondService } from './app/second.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [FirstService, SecondService],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  firstService = inject(FirstService);
}

bootstrapApplication(App);


Above method is the best approach, but you have other options also.
Inherit the second service.
First Service:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SecondService } from './second.service';

@Injectable()
export class FirstService extends SecondService {
  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
    this.test(http);
  }
}

Second Service:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SecondService {
  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {}

  test() {
    console.log('from second service');
  }
}

Initialize the second service as a traditional class
You will have to access the second service as a class and only through the first service, it is not visible in angular DI, and you will have to provider the dependencies to the service (E.g.: HttpClient)
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SecondService } from './second.service';

@Injectable()
export class FirstService {
  secondService!: SecondService;
  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
    this.secondService = new SecondService(http); // <- create a new instance
    // this exists only inside first service.
  }
}


I am getting errors when adding my service to a component's providers array unless I use providedIn. This is what I found so confusing. I just reproduced it right now by removing providedIn from a service, I'm immediately presented with NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for _xService! Besides which, I'm trying to inject "xservice" into "yservice" and getting the same result (when including yservice in the component's provider array)

@emery.noel please replicate the exact error on stackblitz with the minimal code, so that I can check what went wrong?
